# Rails polymorphic relationship - need to use both has_many and has_one

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, polymorphism

Here are the models/relationships from the Rails Guides example on polymorphism:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

In my case a `Product` with many `Pictures` is fine, but I don't want an `Employee` to ever have more than one `Picture`.  I want the `Employee` model to be:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picture, :as => :imageable
end
```

This would allow me to use `@employee.picture`  rather than  `@employee.pictures.first` (using @employee.pictures.first has just a bit of stink to it - isn't representative of the true intent of the relationship.)

Does rails support a `has_one ____  :as => :imageable` relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you must create a join table (something like picturings). Then you will have next models for pictures:

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :picturing, :dependent => :destroy
end

class Picturing < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :picture
  belongs_to :picturable, polymorphic: true
end
```

Product model:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Many pictures
  has_many :picturing, as: :picturable
end
```

Employee model:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :picturing, as: :picturable
  has_one :picture, through: :picturing
end
```

Comment: Moved off of this project, so I did not test this answer, but it looks reasonable.  Having the intermediary structure (picturing) in place to support the has_one relationship has some "smell" to it and isn't what I was looking for, but your approach is well thought out and seems viable.  If I come back to this in the near future I'll test it out.

Comment: You are right it's not good have joining table for one-to-one relationship, but it's simplest way. 

The good solution is having something like 'thread', model (Employee or Product) will belongs to thread and model's thread must have constraints(images count - 1,2 or infinity)